# Retrieve Subcollection in StreamBuilder (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a StreamBuilder in my Flutter app which I can use to retrieve data in a document:

```
class Example extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  ListView.builder(
  itemCount: aCollection.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
  return Card(
    child: Row(
      children: <Widget>[
         Text(aCollection[index].data['area']), // Return Area
```

How can I retrieve data in a Subcollection? Something along the lines of:

`aCollection[index]['aDoc']**[aSubCollection]**.data['field']`

I'm not sure of the correct syntax - would be great if someone can point me in the right direction!

Database Example Screenshot:
[image: img]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `aCollection[index]` is a [`DocumentSnapshot`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot-class.html), then you can get a `CollectionReference` to a subcollection with `aCollection[index].reference.collection("aSubCollection")`.

Comment: Thank you! Looks like I'm almost there with **"aCollection[index].reference.collection('aSubCollection').document(docID).data['title']"**, but getting "Document Reference has no instance getter of 'data'. What is the correct syntax for querying the data inside that subcollection using the above method?

Comment: After `document(docID)` you have a [`DocumentReference`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference-class.html), which is just a reference to a document and doesn't contain any data yet. You'll need to [`get()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference/get.html) that document from the server, which then gives you a `DocumentSnapshot` again. The reference docs are quite easy to navigate, as long as you pay attention to the types.